# BST insertion and in order traversal

Tags: java, tree

```
package com.goman;

public class BST {

    private BST left;
    private BST right;
    private int data;

    public BST(int data, BST left, BST right){
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public BST insert(BST node, BST root){
        if(root == null){
            return node;
        }

        if(root.data > node.data){
            root.left = insert(node, root.left);
        } else if(root.data < node.data){
            root.right = insert(node, root.right);
        } else{
            System.out.println("Duplicate valuesa are not allowed");
            return root;
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BST [left=" + left + ",right=" + right + ",data=" + data
                + "]";
    }

    public void inOrder(BST root){
        if(root==null){
            return;
        }
        inOrder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.data);
        inOrder(root.right);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        BST root = new BST(5, null, null);
        root.insert(new BST(3, null, null), root);
        root.insert(new BST(8, null, null), root);
        root.insert(new BST(2, null, null), root);
        root.insert(new BST(4, null, null), root);
        root.inOrder(root);
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Broken API

The class name `BST` suggests that it's a binary search tree,
but it's not.
It's a node (in a binary tree), with private references to other nodes.

If it's intended to be a node in a binary search tree,
its API is broken.
The `insert` method takes two parameters,
both of them `BST` instances.
It works fine when the first parameter is a `BST` instance *without children* (left and right nodes both null),
but if you pass to it two nodes with children,
the result will be no longer a binary search tree,
for example:

```
BST root = new BST(5, null, null);
root.insert(new BST(3, null, null), root);

BST root2 = new BST(7, null, null);
root2.insert(new BST(3, null, null), root2);

root2.insert(root2, root);
root.inOrder(root);

System.out.println(root);
```

This will output:

> ```
> 3
> 5
> 3
> 7
> BST [left=BST [left=null,right=null,data=3],right=BST [left=BST [left=null,right=null,data=3],right=null,data=7],data=5]
> ```

The result corresponds to this tree, which is not a binary search tree:

```
  5
 / \
3   7
   /
  3
```

You could avoid this by allowing to pass as parameter only data, not another `BST` instance.

Note that the constructor suffers from the same problem,
because the `left` and `right` parameters to insert arbitrary `BST` instances with children,
breaking the binary search tree property.

#### Strange API

The `insert` method doesn't use any fields or methods of the instance.
It could have been a `static` method.
It would have made more sense to use this method signature:

```
public void insert(int data) {
```

This method could use `this.data`, `this.left`, and `this.right` to perform inserting a new value,
and it could successfully protect the binary search tree property.

The `inOrder` method has the same issue.
I suggest to drop the `BST` argument.

After you rewrite the `insert` method this way,
and also drop the dangerous `left` and `right` constructor parameters,
the example code in your question will become simpler and more natural too:

```
BST root = new BST(5);
root.insert(3);
root.insert(8);
root.insert(2);
root.insert(4);
root.inOrder();
System.out.println(root);
```

#### Extension ideas

Instead of `int` as the data,
you could make this class generic,
by declaring as `public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>>`,
and using type `T` everywhere instead of `int`,
and rewriting `x < y` comparisons with `x.compareTo(y) < 0`.

Instead of `inOrder` printing `data`,
you could allow a `Consumer<T>` argument,
to let users decide what they want to do with the visited nodes.
For example, if you rewrite `inOrder` like this:

```
public void inOrder(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    left.inOrder(consumer);
    consumer.accept(data);
    right.inOrder(consumer);
}
```

Then users could print the node values in in-order with:

```
root.inOrder(System.out::println);
```

#### `toString` value hard to read

The `toString` method returns this for the tree in your example:

> ```
> BST [left=BST [left=BST [left=null,right=null,data=2],right=BST [left=null,right=null,data=4],data=3],right=BST [left=null,right=null,data=8],data=5]
> ```

This is hard to read, because the data is printed after the children.
I suggest to print data before the children,
and also the implementation maybe slightly easier to read using `String.format`:

```
return String.format("BST [data=%s,left=%s,right=%s]", data, left, right);
```